# sessionDestroyed in play framework

Tags: playframework, listener, playframework-1.x

Im using Play 1.2.5. I know we have an option to capture session destroy event in servlets. How do we capture session destroy event in play framework. I search through the methods in Play plug ins, but I couldn't find. Please help me if any one aware of.

Comment: I'm wondering why you're trying to catch that event?  Unless mistaken, sessions are tied with cookie expiration in play 1.2.5 - I do not recall seeing a callback associated with that timeout in play.

Comment: Yes, session are tied with cookies. I would like to make some DB updates when session time out happens. This feature is available in Servlets as sessions are maintained at server side. But I'm not sure how do we achieve the same feature in Play framework

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can detect browser close events directly via play framework.  You can schedule expiration based on the application.session.maxAge parameter (this will not catch browser close events).  One other approach would be to rely on javascript to detect the browser close event via **onunload** & **onbeforeunload**.  Using these events, you can send a  xhr message to the server side notifying the browser close event to the server (I have not tried it but I think it will work).  Please update the link if it does not.  Hope it helps.

Comment: were you able to find a different solution?